# firebase and google shortener with the same API key

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-security, google-url-shortener

As I understood, expose the API key it is not a security risk if I add validation rules to my database as it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public?answertab=oldest#tab-top),

```
var config = {
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>', // this key
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};
```

I also understood that I can call google shortener API with the firebase API key, now it is risky, anyone can call google shortener API with my firebase API key, how I can avoid this

Comment: What API key are you talking about? Because much of the Firebase configuration data is explicitly meant to be included in the client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: the apiKey that I should include in the client, with this key I success to invoke google shortener API @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Hmmm..... I don't know. Let me ask around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Keys are generic identifiers for access across Google APIs - they're not just for Firebase. They are used for API access when you don't need to identify as a specific user (where you would use an OAuth access token).

API keys identify that your project is making a call like passing a project ID, but, importantly, can be regenerated - so if one is being used by a bad actor, you can delete it.

So how do you use these API keys without opening yourself up to someone spamming another API?

**Add a domain restriction**. Browser based keys can be restricted to require being on a certain domain. You can add these from the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_):

1. Go to the 'Credentials' page for your project
2. Find your API key and select it
3. Select 'HTTP referrers (websites)'
4. Add each of your domains

Be careful with this! Make sure you cover all the domain you're running on, or you will block access (for example if you have a .com and .es version of your site, make sure both domains are whitelisted).

**Don't enable the API**. If you don't need URL shortener on in the Firebase project, you can disable it from the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/urlshortener.googleapis.com/overview?project=_). Most APIs start disabled, and several types of API can't be called with an API key any way (they require a service account which is a bit more secure).

Comment: first of all thanks for this explanation, if I call google shortener from firebase functions what the HTTP referrer I should define @IanBerber

Comment: For Functions usage I would generate a separate API key (you can do it from the console) and don't attach any restrictions - but also don't share it publicly! You can also use a service account to call the API (which is even more secure!) but a little more work.